# Javascript || not working properly

Tags: javascript

I have this JS function, which should check if there is a firstChild on the element, if there isnt a paragraph should be created with the || document.createElement("p"), but i get an error, Cannot read firstChild property of null

EDIT: shouldnt have the "if(element) on the code, i was about ot try something with that, but it was not there when i had the error

```
function    update(element,content,klass)   {
    var p   =   element.firstChild  ||  document.createElement("p");        
    p.textContent   =   content;
    element.appendChild(p);
    if(klass)   {
    p.className =   klass;
    }
}
```

complete JS file

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var rainbow = ["red","orange","yellow","green","blue","indigo","violet"];
////    dom references  ////
var $question   =   document.getElementById("question");
var $score  =   document.getElementById("score");
var $feedback   =   document.getElementById("feedback");


function    update(element,content,klass)   {
    var p   =   element.firstChild  ||  document.createElement("p");

    p.textContent   =   content;
    element.appendChild(p);
    if(klass)   {
    p.className =   klass;
    }
}


var score = 0;

var quiz = {
    "name": "Super Hero Name Quiz",
    "description": "How many super heroes can you name",
    "question": "What is the real name of ",
    "questions": [
        {"question" : "Superman", "answer": "Clarke Kent"},
        {"question" : "Batman" , "answer": "Bruce Wayne"},
        {"question" : "Wonder Woman", "answer": "Dianna Prince"}
    ]
}




function play(quiz){
    for(var i= 0,question,answer,max=quiz.questions.length;i<max;i++){
        question = quiz.questions[i].question;
        answer = ask(question);
        check(answer,i);
    }
    gameOver();

}
play(quiz);

function ask(question){
    update($question,quiz.question + question)
    return prompt("Enter your awnser");
}
function check(answer,index){
    if(answer === quiz.questions[index].answer){
        update($feedback,"Correct!","right");
        score++;
    }
    else{
        update($feedback,"Wrong!","wrong");
    }

}


function gameOver(){

        update($question,"Game  Over,   you scored  "   +   score   +   "points");
}
```

Html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="A quiz game for ninjas">
<meta name="author" content="DAZ">
<title>Quiz Ninja</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Quiz Ninja!</h1>
<p>Score:   <strong id="score">0</strong></p>   
</header>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<section id="question">
    <p>Question:</p>
</section>
<section id="feedback">
    <p>Feedback</p>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure why i get NULL on $question and $feedback

Comment: Sounds like your `element` parameter is null. You might want to try something like `var p   =   element && element.firstChild  ||  document.createElement("p");`

Comment: Your code checks to see whether `element` is non-null, but it does so *after* it attempts to reference one of its properties (and then it makes another attempt after that even if it was `null` or `undefined`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, `null.someFunction` does not return undefined and instead throws a `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'null.someFunction')`. This is because Javascript cannot get properties of nonexistent variables. This is the same with `undefined.someFunction`.

The `||` operator returns the first truthy value that it's given, truthy meaning not `null` or `undefined` or `0`. However, to find their value it must first evaluate them. Because your code tries to get `element.firstChild` first, it fails because element is null or undefined. The `||` operator does not get to run if element.firstChild fails.

Instead, you can check if element is defined before using it.

```
var p;
if(element)
    p   =   element.firstChild  ||  document.createElement("p");
else
    p   =   document.createElement("p");
```

To condense this down into one line, you can use a ternary operator

```
var p   =   element ? element.firstChild : false  ||  document.createElement("p");
```

Now you'll probably have the error where `element` is not defined at

```
element.appendChild(p);
```

This is because you removed the if statement in your edit.

Another thing, the Javascript file is loaded and executed the moment it finds the script tag. That means it can't find your sections because they haven't been loaded yet. To fix this, move the script to the bottom after everything it needs before it loads:

```
<section id="question">
    <p>Question:</p>
</section>
<section id="feedback">
    <p>Feedback</p>
</section>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Then, the tags will be loaded and put in the page and the script will be run and find the tags.

Another option to fix this is using Jquery's `$(document).ready(function(){})`

If you wrap all your code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // your code
});
```

Jquery will wait for the page to fully load before running your code.

Comment: Yeah i see it, not sure why i gett null at question and feedback, i have two sections with those ID's.

Comment: Oh found the real issue, the `<script>` tag must be below your elements @DanielBezerraDeMenezes - Edited the post to add that

Comment: You're right script was at the wrong place, now i eveything to be right, but for some reason the content of the html only loads after the prompt with the questions are over....any idea? in the console eveything runs fine, i printed the questions / awnsers and they work, but nothing happens on the screen only after its over

Comment: Nevermind...it was a bug on Google Chrome lol. Works fine on firefox, thanks for the help my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Either `$question` or `$feedback` is null. Check your markup and make sure that there is an element defined with `id='question'`, and an element defined with `id='feedback'`.

Also, the logic in your `update` function seems a little out of order. You are checking whether your `element` is null or not, but doing that after you access one of the `element`'s properties. This might better serve you:

```
function update(element,content,klass) {
    if(element) {
        var p = element.firstChild || document.createElement("p");
        element.appendChild(p);
        p.textContent = content;
        if(klass) {
            p.className = klass;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your snippet, `p` is defined conditionally as part of the check for `element`. If `element` doesn't exist, wouldn't the line `p.textContent = content` throw an error since `p` is not defined in that case?

Comment: Yes, @CRice. Thank you for pointing that out. I have updated.

Comment: My bad, if(element) wasnt in the original code, i was just about to try something with it